# Which ports does android use?

Tags: android, proxy

I have UnknownHostExeption, when i am using proxy. My App works finy in networks without proxy or with some proxies( not everyone). 
I am aware that I need to setup proxy setings for networks with them
for device: wify settings - advance - wifi proxy
emulator: wireless networks - mobile networks - access points - telkia - proxy|port.
I wish to know which essential options I have to ask admins to unlock for stable network comunications.

```
07-18 08:51:26.780: W/System.err(302): java.net.UnknownHostException: mirkvartir.ua
07-18 08:51:26.780: W/System.err(302):  at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:513)
07-18 08:51:26.780: W/System.err(302):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:278)
07-18 08:51:26.780: W/System.err(302):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:242)
07-18 08:51:26.780: W/System.err(302):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:136)
07-18 08:51:26.780: W/System.err(302):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
07-18 08:51:26.780: W/System.err(302):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
07-18 08:51:26.780: W/System.err(302):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:348)
07-18 08:51:26.780: W/System.err(302):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
07-18 08:51:26.780: W/System.err(302):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
07-18 08:51:26.780: W/System.err(302):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
07-18 08:51:26.780: W/System.err(302):  at ua.mirkvartir.android.frontend.adapter.JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(JSONParser.java:98)
07-18 08:51:26.780: W/System.err(302):  at ua.mirkvartir.android.frontend.adapter.UserFunctions.loginUser(UserFunctions.java:76)
07-18 08:51:26.787: W/System.err(302):  at ua.mirkvartir.android.frontend.LoginActivity$Login.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:185)
07-18 08:51:26.787: W/System.err(302):  at ua.mirkvartir.android.frontend.LoginActivity$Login.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:1)
07-18 08:51:26.787: W/System.err(302):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
07-18 08:51:26.787: W/System.err(302):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
07-18 08:51:26.787: W/System.err(302):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
07-18 08:51:26.787: W/System.err(302):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
07-18 08:51:26.787: W/System.err(302):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
07-18 08:51:26.787: W/System.err(302):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is, you cannot tell in general. This is not Android-specific, but depends on your App. You're free to choose the ports it communicates over. Usually, 80 and 443 shouldn't be blocked (http / https) - everything else depends on your App.

What services do you use? If you never specified a port explicitly, they might imply one.

Comment: i am just using httppost

Comment: That should be port 80 then.

Comment: HttpPost post = new HttpPoast(url:80) where 80 is port number. Is it right way to specify port?

Comment: I believe so, given that your argument looks more like `"http://www.mysite.com:80"`.

Comment: Yes it looks like that, but seems problem is in other place